# Resolver edição de textarea com jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, textarea

Eu estou fazendo um cadastro de eventos, com PHP e jQuery, para cadastrar ocorre tudo bem, mas quando eu vou alterar, ocasiona um erro:

Exemplo:
Todos sabemos que quando entramos em uma página pra editar, temos que ter os campos preenchidos já com os dados do banco de dados, isso é um fato.

Só que quando eu mudo o texto do `textarea`, e clico em *submit*, o meu banco de dados não muda o campo, e mesmo tentando mostrar no console, o novo conteúdo não mostra no console, mostra o texto do banco de dados.

Meu campo HTML:

```
<textarea name="post_content" id="post_content" class="form-control tinymce"><?=$result->post_content;?></textarea>
```

Essa é a variavel:

```
var descricao_edit = j("textarea[name='post_content']").val();
```

Script JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var j = jQuery.noConflict();
    j(document).ready(function () {
        var base_url = window.location.origin;
        var btn_enviar = j('#cadastro-dados');

        btn_enviar.on('click', function (event) {
            var base_url = window.location.origin;
            event.preventDefault();

            var categoria = j("input[type=radio][name=post_category]").val();
            var subcategoria = j("#post_category_parent").val();
            var titulo = j("#post_title").val();
            var descricao = j("#post_content").val();
            var id = j("#post_author").val();

            j.ajax({
                url: "<?= INCLUDE_PATH; ?>/modulos/cadastro_evento.php",
                type: 'POST',
                data: 'acao=dados&id=' + id + '&categoria=' + categoria + '&sub=' + subcategoria + '&titulo=' + titulo + '&descricao=' + descricao,
                beforeSend: function () {
                    btn_enviar.attr("disabled", true);
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    j.gritter.add({
                        title: '<i class="fa fa-check"></i> Sucesso!',
                        text: 'Dados registrados com sucesso.',
                        sticky: false,
                        time: ''
                    });

                    btn_enviar.attr("disabled", false);
                    window.location.href = base_url + "/editar/" + data;                    
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    if (data == 'erro') {
                        btn_enviar.attr("disabled", false);
                        alert('Erro ao tentar registrar');
                    }                   
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: O erro vem do código do lado do servidor certamente. Submissão normal ou por ajax?

Comment: bom eu faço com $.ajax();

Comment: o que é esse `j` ? seria o `$` ?

Comment: Porém eu notei aqui que nem o meu cadastrar funciona, eu fiz um teste aqui, e eu fui cadastrar, e no textarea, ao invés de deixar o texto apdrão eu mudei, para fazer um teste, e quando eu submeti, cadastrou no banco de dados como texto padrão, não cadastrou com o texto que eu fiz coisa de doido.

Comment: Sim, o j eu estou utilizando o noConflict();
Eu fiz assim:
var j = jQuery.noConflict();

Comment: Poste a submissão por AJAX que você faz. Para entendermos melhor.

Comment: Acabei de adicionar na descrição

Comment: coloque assim: `'&descricao=' +encodeURIComponent(descricao)` e em todos os outros que podem possuir acentuação

Comment: Nada, sem sucesso, não funcionou, mais a questão não é problema na acentuação, só para detalhar.
É tipo como se não tivesse digitado nada no textarea, e tivesse um texto padrão cadastrando.

Comment: Acho que o problema é na maneira de pegar o conteúdo da `textarea`. Você está utilizando o TinyMCE e, acredito eu, que o valor deste editor não é armazenado diretamente no valor do campo, então fazer `j("#post_content").val()` sempre retornará o valor inicial e não o editado. Veja [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4551834/1452488) uma possível solução.

Comment: Anderson Carlos Woss, eu também estou nesse seu raciocinio de que possa ser o TinyMCe, que está dando pau, pois somente o campo textarea que está com o problema, mais eu realmente não posso deixar de utilizar esse bendito rsrs. Ele é essencial neste projeto.

Comment: Vou tentar a solução do anderson e posto resultados.

Comment: Anderson, no console me mostra este erro: Uncaught TypeError: tinyMCE.getContent is not a function.
Talvez essa solução não seja pra versão que eu utilizo do tinymce que é atualizada.

Comment: Fiz desse jeito: 
<pre>var descricao = tinyMCE.getContent('#post_content');</pre>

Comment: Meu código tinyMCE, está acima dessa função de cadastro

Comment: Pessoal resolvido, vou postar aqui como foi resolvido.

Comment: De acordo com o link que o Anderson Carlos Woss me passou, eu tentei, pois no post tem várias formas de fazer, e eu fui tentando, então para aqueles que tiverem o mesmo problema vai o trecho que eu consegui.<br/>

     var descricao = tinyMCE.get('post_content').getContent();

<br/>Apenas isso conseguir resolver.

Agradeço a todos que foram me ajudando a solucionar o problema e principalmente ao Anderson, por mim informar o caminho da solução.

Até a próxima!

Comment: Eu agora fiquei só com o problema de acentuação, se eu deixar o código que o Everson informou, o texto com acentos fica com caracteres estranhos, mais se eu tirar o código, ele some com todo texto apartir da letra que contem acento. Então fica apenas um pedaço do texto.